# Is docstring max line-length different to normal PEP8 standard?

Tags: python, pylint, docstring, pep8, code-standards

So im looking at some code and bringing it up to PEP 8 standard with the help of pylint and i noticed that if i was using triple quotes for a print statement where the text went past 120 chars (we are allowing 120 instead of 79) pylint didn't complain.
  Is this a bug in pylint **or** does it think it might be a comment and is more lenient with the length of lines **or** does it not care about how far over you go with strings in trippple quotes because you may want to format them that way?

*For clarity*: yes pylint works normally in every other case of going over the line length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having used pylint regularly, I have also noticed this inconsistency. In the [Maximum Line Length section of PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), it says:

> Therefore, please limit **all** lines to a maximum of 79 characters. For flowing long blocks of text (**docstrings or comments**), limiting the length to 72 characters is recommended.

I know that pylint does not at all enforce the 79 character or the 72 character line length limits for docstrings and comments, so I would guess that this is a pylint bug since it is non-compliant with PEP8 in this area.

Comment: Since the recommendation exists to improve readability in width-constricted environments, it wouldn't make sense to have exceptions.

Comment: so it is a bug presumably, i tried to register on the site that does pylint to add an item to the issue tracker the other day, (for a different bug i noticed) still haven't received an email of activation unfortunately .

Answer (score 3):

As pylint maintainer, I can tell this is definitly a bug.

@Jacxel : if you've trouble registering on logilab.org, you can still post the pb on the python-projects@logilab.org mailing list

thanks